# Jenkins. Invalid agent type "docker" specified. Must be one of [any, label, none]

Tags: node.js, docker, jenkins

My JenkinsFile looks like:

```
pipeline {
    agent { 
        docker { 
            image 'node:12.16.2'
            args '-p 3000:3000'
        } 
    }
    stages {
        stage('Build') {
            steps {
                sh 'node --version'
                sh 'npm install'
                sh 'npm run build'
            }
        }
        stage ('Deliver') {
            steps {
                sh 'readlink -f ./package.json'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I used to have Jenkins locally and this configuration worked, but I deployed it to a remote server and get the following error:

```
WorkflowScript: 3: Invalid agent type "docker" specified. Must be one of [any, label, none] @ line 3, column 9.
           docker {
```

I could not find a solution to this problem on the Internet, please help me

Comment: This is probably due to the Docker Pipeline plugin not being installed.

Comment: I installed the plugin, indicated the docker host in the global settings, but still gives this error

Answer (score 119, accepted):

You have to install 2 plugins: `Docker plugin` and `Docker Pipeline`.

Go to Jenkins root page > Manage Jenkins > Manage Plugins > Available and search for the plugins. (Learnt from [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=m5IFbG07V-c)).

Comment: for some reason this does not help

Comment: after a complete reinstall and installing all necessary plugins,i have this error: ‘Jenkins’ doesn’t have label ‘docker’

Comment: @Zimovik007 well, I used [this tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-continuous-integration-pipelines-in-jenkins-on-ubuntu-16-04). I have done all the pre-requisite steps (though for Ubuntu 18.04, can be found on DigitaOcean as well) and the only obstacle was these 2 plugins I mentioned in the comment above. You may follow the same route and see what it brings. For me I got a working Jenkins pipeline. Note that the Node app they use is far out of date and will not work. It would require numerous updates. Though the pipeline itself will work.

Comment: hmm, I think I’ve been doing something wrong all this time

Comment: @Zimovik007 you may find it useful to see the Continous Delivery counterpart [here](https://medium.com/@mosheezderman/how-to-set-up-ci-cd-pipeline-for-a-node-js-app-with-jenkins-c51581cc783c) for the CI part above.

Comment: Just Docker Pipeline plugin should be enough.

Comment: @KonstantinPelepelin Did you check if only Docker Pipeline is enough? Are you sure about that?

Comment: @CharlesXu When I wrote that comment I was sure. If I remember correctly, "Docker plugin" exposes Docker API to pipeline scripts, which is not used directly above, so it shouldn't be needed.

Answer (score 2):

instead of
agent {
docker {
image 'node:12.16.2'
args '-p 3000:3000'
}
}

try
agent {
any {
image 'node:12.16.2'
args '-p 3000:3000'
}
}

that worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

For those that are using CasC you might want to include in plugin declaration

```
docker:latest
docker-commons:latest
docker-workflow:latest
```

Comment: I think `docker` should be `docker-plugin`