# Jenkins. Invalid agent type "docker" specified

Tags: docker, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

When I try to use agent as docker in jenkins file, it fails with the error "Invalid agent type docker specified."

Verified that ***Docker*** and ***Docker Pipeline*** plugins are installed.

Have checked the link for a solution: [Jenkins. Invalid agent type "docker" specified. Must be one of [any, label, none]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62253474/jenkins-invalid-agent-type-docker-specified-must-be-one-of-any-label-none)

Works if I use **agent** as **any** instead of docker but not sure why it was failing if we use docker alone.

Verified the below plugins are installed in jenkins server under /plugins as well. Still facing same issue.

docker-commons
docker-workflow
docker-plugin

Please can anyone help with resolving this

Comment: You need to add label `docker` to the agent when you register agent to Jenkins controller(master).  And you can use any string as the label,  using `docker` is straightly tell user this agent installed Docker.  `docker` label is not installed together with Docker and Docker Pipeline plugin, they have no binded connection.   I you have one agent installed Docker and its label is `abc`, you can  use `agent {label 'abc'}`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
pipeline {
    docker {    
        label "${RUNNING_NODE}"
        image "DockerImage"
        args "--privileged -v /dev:/dev"
    }
}
```

Explain:

- Label: which server choose to run
- Image: name of docker image
- args: it likes 'parameters' when u use docker run command. (optional)